# When adding a weak acid to a strong base in an acid-base titration, why does multiplying the pKa of the acid by two give the pH at neutralisation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, titration

I'm not sure if the premise of the question is even correct, but when adding ethanoic acid to sodium hydroxide solution, I was told that the pH at the point of neutralisation should be around 2x the pKa of ethanoic acid (so around 9.52), and the data I collected showed this as well. Why is this the case? I know that at the half equivalence point pH = pKa when adding a strong base to a weak acid, so what changed in this scenario?

Comment: You will find your answer searching for "neutralization of a weak acid with a strong base".

Comment: pH=7 + 0.5(pKa + log c) (simplified but approximately valid for most cases)